# How to use Material UI icons in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and am working on an existing React component. I need to include an icon and noticed that some were already being brought in, like:

```
import KeyboardArrowLeftIcon from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/keyboard-arrow-left';
```

I couldn't locate the folder (`material-ui/svg-icons/action/`), but tried to add a new icon:

```
import KeyboardArrowRightIcon from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/keyboard-arrow-right';
```

However, this generates an error on compiling.

Would anyone know how I could add a new icon? Or, why there is no apparent director for these icons?

Comment: what is that compilation error? and what package you are using pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing the dependencies first. Here is the link to [Material Icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/icons)

Comment: Thanks @Deepak Brahmania, but wouldn't they already be installed since the other icons work?

Comment: I didn't know I had to install that dependancy, but also I had the wrong path for the particular icon I wanted.

Comment: How is this an accepted answer? it should be a comment since it does not answer in a useable way.

Answer (score 44):

1. install material icon: `npm install @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons`
2. import the icon you will use: `import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';`
3. use the icon: `<MenuIcon/>`

You can also use https://material-ui.com/components/material-icons/ to search for the icon you need.

Comment: I found that it has a dependency with `@material-ui/core` also. So, you need to run `npm install @material-ui/core` also.

Comment: This solution crashes because `Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon'` when importing one of the icons

Answer (score 4):

it is also possible to import them via CDN by calling the links in index.html from the public folder.

simply copy&paste the links below in head.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';

<EditIcon />
```

[material-ui](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/)

Answer (score 2):

There's a `material-icons-react` lib that makes using the icons easy.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-icons-react

Here's a quick icon reference. 
https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=nature_people&style=baseline

Comment: That was the best one

Answer (score 1):

The following import worked for me.

```
import ReplayIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Replay";
```

Answer (score 0):

to import the icons from Material-UI into React.js you must use Pascal Case ( keyboard-arrow-right becomes KeyboardArrowRight ).
About the path, I am using  'import ArrowBack from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowBack', you may not be using the "at" sign in material-ui (when installing), but you should check that the directory you are pointing to contains a lot of JS files with the Icon name in PascalCase ("AccessAlarm.js" is the first icon/file that shows up in my projects).

Answer (score 0):

To do so, add one of the following command lines, depending on whether you do it with npm or yarn, into your project:

```
npm install @material-ui/core

yarn add @material-ui/core
```

A detailed step-by-step guide is available [here](https://flatlogic.com/blog/material-ui-icons-in-react/).

Answer (score 0):

For clear button add this at the very top of your page:

import ClearIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Clear";

```
   <Button
         style={{
                position: "absolute" ,
                left: "0" ,
                top: "0" ,
                zIndex: "2"      
                }}
                type="button"
                variant="light"
                onClick={() => deleteFileHandler(x)}
                startIcon={<ClearIcon />}
          >
```