# How do I render a Material UI icon in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I'm new to React and want to render a Material UI icon (from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/icons) in an existing component.

I noticed that they person who previously worked on the component has included icons with an attribute, like:

```
<FieldWrapper scrollToOnFocus icon={<SomeMaterialIcon />}>
```

But I need to add my icon like within some existing html, eg:

```
<a href="/somewhere">Read more ICON HERE</a>
```

I am unsure how to do this. Adding `{<SomeMaterialIcon />}` or `<SomeMaterialIcon />` directly to the line of HTML breaks the component.

Would anyone know how to do this?

Comment: How exactly component breaks? Could you please provide a context - so a little bit more code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Material UI icons in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829728/how-to-use-material-ui-icons-in-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've already installed the package (@material-ui/icons) and imported the Icon correctly, it should be as simple as `<SomeMaterialIcon />`.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <a href="/somewhere"><AddIcon /></a>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit 62v3mr03kk]