# Material ui icons react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Who can help me with this. I need this icons from material ui but I can't find info how I can make it

[image]

Comment: Duplicate question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829728/how-to-use-material-ui-icons-in-react

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to import the icon in your component then you can use the following code as example:

```
import FacebookIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Facebook";

const YourComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <span>...some other content</span>
    <FacebookIcon />
  </div>
);

export default YourComponent;
```

If you need to have also a background for your image you can do something like that:

```
<div style={{ backgroundColor: "#1877d1", padding: "1rem", display: "inline-block" }}>
  <FacebookIcon />
</div>
```

So you need to wrap the icon in a `div` with a stile.

Comment: I have imported and did all the stuff but I want the icons to have background. Does material-ui have sth to make icons be like in photo or should I make it

Answer (score 0):

You can install Material-UI Icons

> with npm  : npm install @material-ui/icons
>
> with yarn : yarn add @material-ui/icons

and import material-UI icons : [link](https://material-ui.com/components/material-icons/)

Comment: I need to make filled icons. But I dont know which property I should give

Comment: Put it in a container and give it a backgroundColor. There is not any specific property for it